# Printing data from remote server to screen using recylerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, remote-server, android-developer-api

Here is the Adapter class

```
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListViewHolder>() {

    var movieList: ArrayList<MovieDetailResponse>? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieListViewHolder {
        return MovieListViewHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movieList?.size ?:0
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieListViewHolder, position: Int) {
     holder.bind(movieList?.get(position))
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewHolder Data class

```
data class Put (
    val adult:Boolean,
    val backdrop_path:String?,
    val budget:Int,
    val genres: List<Genres>,
    val homepage:String?,
    val id:Int,
    val imdb_id:String?,
    val original_language:String,
    val original_title:String,
    var overview:String?,
    val popularity:Number,
    val poster_path:String?,
    val release_date:String,
    val revenue:Int,
    val runtime:Int?,
    val tagline:String?,
    var title:String,
    val video:Boolean,
    val vote_average:Number,
    val vote_count:Int
)
```

I send the request to the remote server, the response is received, but the movie List null is returned

Comment: Add bind function code in question

Comment: can you add also the activity and a part of your code with a network request? For now, what I see is that you don't update your `movieList`